# K-mean clustering, why different initial positions of the clusters influence on the final clustering result?

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am not sure whether this question is suitable here. Anyway, it seems like people here are helpful. So here is my question.

In case of k-mean clustering, it is necessary to give the initial positions of the clusters.
why different initial positions of the clusters influence on the final clustering result?

Comment: We also know in-depth trivia about The Princess Bride, The Wire, optimal strategies for Scrabble, and non-optimal strategies for picking up women but that doesn't mean questions about such are appropriate here.

Comment: @Jason: sorry for posting such an inappropriate question here. Could admin delete it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Eh, no need to be sorry; it's an interesting question. I was just trying to be humorous. I'm often unsuccessful at that.

Comment: @Jason: Ok. Maybe i didnt catch your joke because of my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use k-means, the problem you really want to solve is to minimize the within cluster sum of squares (WCSS). There is no efficient way to solve this problem exactly (even for 2-d points). In more technical terms WCSS is an NP-hard problem.

k-means is an iterative method that finds an approximate solution to the WCSS problem, this general scheme k-means uses is an expectation-maximization method. Most iterative methods require a starting point, and in general the quality of the solution will depend on the starting point.